# How to set test URL in LoadTest in LoadAndPerformanceTestProject - Basic

Tags: asp.net, testing, azure, load, test-project

This question is very basic if you previously used this tools, but I just spent 2 hours and havent figured it out, so please help.
It is the first time I try to test a REST service and how many concurrent users can it take. While LoadStorm looks like the best product for something like this, I want something free.

I began using the LoadAndPerformanceTestProject project in Visual Studio. I created a loadTest, as you can see in the image, but I have no idea how to set the url I want to test. (see image below)
[image]
Questions:
1) where do you set the url you want to test and the request parameters for my REST service?
2) is this tool just a programs that runs on my machine and makes requests to the server?
3) what can I do to run it in the cloud so I can get more accurate results? I have a MSDN subscription, and the URL I use is actually my project that is in Azure.

These are a lot of questions, but I don't see any tutorial online on how to use this feature. I saw this video [enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sc9M6NN_VmU) but unfortunately when I go to TEST in the menu bar, I have different options from the video - see picture bellow. In the video is seams like he doesn't have to add a LoadAndPerformanceTestProject at all.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create one or more Web Performance Tests. It's in this test that you define which urls should be hit in the test and how it should happen (GET, POST, loop, conditions, headers, ...). You can add a new Web Performance Test by simply right clicking your project, Add, New Web Performance Test.

[image]

After you created your test, simply add them in a scenario of your load test:

[image]

This should get you started. To get the most out of load testing I suggest you do some more reading about the topic because there's a lot more to it.

Comment: does the test process run on my machine? can it run in the cloud?

Comment: The test will typically run in Visual Studio. So it depends where you run Visual Studio (you can do this locally or on a VM in the cloud). Or you can take a look at Test Controllers and Test Agents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728093.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For running load test in cloud you can follow the links here
http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/load-test-your-app-vs

Do let me know if you need any help.